# Media Queries to target Tablet

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, tablet, retina-display

I am creating a site header / menu for a responsive site.  I am using breakpoints of 960px and above for a desktop menu with hover states and dropdowns, and breakpoints 959px and below for a mobile menu display.  This works for most use cases, but I also want the mobile menu to display on tablets in landscape mode, which are typically wider than the 960 breakpoint.  I am trying to target these tablets with CSS media queries only, no JavaScript.

I originally thought to use pixel-ratio, something like this:

```
@media (max-width:959px), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5) {
  /*mobile styles here*/
}
@media (min-width:960px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.499) {
  /*desktop styles here*/
}
```

This worked at first, but then I realized higher resolution Retina displays on desktops were getting the mobile menu.  Unfortunately I need to support older versions of iOS (down to 7), so I cannot rely on Media Queries Level 4 and use the interaction queries.

Can anyone help with a media query set that can help me?  I need to be able to set styles that apply to both widths less than 960 and tablets larger than 960, and set styles that apply to widths above 960 that are not tablets.

Thanks!